# Convert Html fields to Struts2 tags

Tags: html, user-interface, struts2, jsp-tags

I am new to struts2... I designed a page in plain html.. now i have use this html page in struts2 project.. how can i convert html field elements to Struts2 ui tags ??? 
My html page looks like:

```
<tr>
    <td class="style4">**Customer Name***</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Scr_Inq_CName" class="body-fieldsTextFields" id="Scr_Inq_CName_id" tabindex="4" onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(event);"/></td>                 
</tr>
```

I have assigned style(style4) to a label "**Customer name**" and style(body-fieldsTextFields) to text box and also i have performed validation on this..

When i use Struts-tag

It displays text field with style(body-fieldsTextFields) applied, When i run project... But **Customer name** label is displayed in separate row `<tr><td>Customer name</td></tr>`.

And text field is displayed in below table row `<tr>`. i found this kind of disorder using **FireBug**.

how to apply **style4** to **Customer name** label and **body-fieldsTextFields** style to all **textfields** and also how can i make both label and text field to be displayed in same row ?????

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr>
    <td class="style4">**Customer Name***</td>
    <td><s:textfield cssClass="body-fieldsTextFields" theme="simple" name="Scr_Inq_CName" id="Scr_Inq_CName_id" onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(event);"/></td>                 
</tr>
```

This will give you what you want

`theme="simple"` will remove the struts styling. `cssClass` attribute is used by struts2 tags to use css classes.

Also take a look at Steven's comment.You need to increase your accept rate.

Answer (score 0):

For the alignment problem I guess you have some errors in your CSS rules for **style4**, you should check if you have put some display:block or similar rules that would make the next cell go under the first, otherwise the html is correct.

If you prefer creating a real label you could do this (I'm using Struts tags):

```
<tr>
   <td><label for="Scr_Inq_CName_id">**Customer Name**</label></td>
   <td><html:text property="Scr_Inq_CName" styleClass="body-fieldsTextFields" styleId="Scr_Inq_CName_id" tabindex="4" onkeypress="return CommonKeyPressIsAlpha(event);" /></td>
</tr>
```

For the CSS Rule, you can use attribute selectors:

```
input[type="text"]{
   //This rule is valid for every input of type text, or textfield.
}
```

The two fields as I said should already be visible on same row.

Comment: I want to separate "Enter your Name" in <td> and textFiled in other <td>
when i do that these 2 td aren't appear in the same vertical alignment.
the first one in top and other in bottom i dont know why that happened???
im forced to do like this:
<s:textfield label="Enter your Name" value="" required="true" name="userBean.userName"></s:textfield>
this doesnt allow me to give label style sheet and the text field has another style sheet.
i build a css but i think it still not taken .
how to use custom cascade style sheet for using it to Struts2